# Generating Kotlin interface class from Java generates errors

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I hava a Java interface class that has been converted to Kotlin. On Conversion it creates a lot of errors on the other files as the getters and setters are used.

The Java interface class:

```
public interface ValueFormElement extends BaseElement {


    Pair<Boolean, Hashtable<String,String>> getValue();

    String getName();

    void setName(String name);
    void setValue(String value);


}
```

On conversion it removes the getter and am using the getter in other classes. This is the generated Kotlin class

```
interface ValueFormElement : BaseElement {


    val value: Pair<Boolean, Hashtable<String, String>>

    var name: String
    fun setValue(value: String)


}
```

If anyone has a way of implementing or doing it cleanly with get and set without affecting the rest of the code ,please show me or direct me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `var`, both a get/set method will be generated for use in Java. For `val` however, only a get method is provided (since val implies read-only). You can just consolidate to two `var`s to match the Java implementation:

```
interface ValueFormElement : BaseElement {
  var value: Pair<Boolean, Hashtable<String, String>>
  var name: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code using this Kotlin interface will still see getters and setters, same as before, so they won't be affected. Only the Kotlin code will be. And if you aren't prepared to fix them at the moment, I wouldn't bother converting the interface to Kotlin at all.

While it's possible to write

```
fun getName(): String
```

etc. in a Kotlin interface, it'll make it *less* usable than the Java version is. Namely, Kotlin won't let you write `x.value` or `x.name = ...`.